# Проблема с логикой if-else

Tags: c, if

Не видит if (x<0) printf ("\n Функцiя не iснує \n"); if (x>=20) printf ("\n Функцiя не iснує \n").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

 int main()

 {

 setlocale (LC_ALL, "Ukr");
 float x, y;

 printf ("\n Введiть значення x = ");
 scanf ("%f", &x);

{

if (x<-4) printf ("\n y = %f \n", x-5);
else if (x<0) printf ("\n Функцiя не iснує \n");
     else if (0<=x<20) printf ("\n y = %f \n", 9 * pow(x,4) + 1);
          else if (x>0) printf ("\n Функцiя не iснує \n");
               else if (31<=x<=32) printf ("\n y = %f \n", 9 * pow(x,4) + 1);
                    else if (x>=20) printf ("\n Функцiя не iснує \n");

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Ну, `x<0` - работает, введите -1, например... А вот всякие `0<=x<20` отрабатывает верно, но не так , **как вы думаете**. Оно считает `(0<=x)<20` - ну, а `0<=x` дает либо 0, либо 1 - так что это условие всегда верно...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: А это ничего, что у вас условия несколько не то чтобы противоречивы... но, например (если бы работало так, как вы хотите), до ветви от 31 до 32 и далее дело просто не дойдет?... А кстати, приведите **начальное условие**, а то что-то странно ваш код выглядит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так писать

```
31<=x<=32
```

нельзя. Оно хоть и компилится, но не работает, как ожидается

Надо вот так

```
31 <= x &&  x <= 32
```

хотя по факту это

```
x == 31 || x == 32
```

и там таких ещё много.

Comment: Спасибо, но можно ли обойтись без логических операторов ?

Comment: @Kodarak вложенные `if`-ы сделать, но так читабельней будет

Comment: можно, сделать функцию на каждый вариант и потом сделать массив таких функций.

Comment: @Kodarak В Си++ можно перегрузить оператор, но поможет ли это, не уверен.

Comment: Вы не можете перегрузить оператор <, > и другие для встроенных типов (int, float).